# Xcode: Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak

I tried to run Xcode apps on my jailbroken iPod Touch 2G by using JailCoder (which seems to be doing its job) and AppSync on my iPod touch (running iOS v4.2.1, the highest allowed for armv6 I believe) and got this error message for every build.

I just restored my iPod touch about 3 weeks ago and promptly jailbroke it. And it worked fine since except for this. Even blank template Xcode projects, which and runs perfect on both the iPhone and iPad simulators always gets this fatal error and this one exclusively. I even make sure to set the deployment target to 4.2 and make sure armv6 and armv7 are both supported.

```
/bin/sh -c /Users/Zach/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-run-ddvzosbhsvraawfdopekdoyocney/Build/Intermediates/test-run.build/Debug-iphoneos/test-run.build/Script-50524F424C454D533F.sh

iPhone Developer: ambiguous (matches "iPhone Developer" and "iPhone Developer" in /Users/Zach/Library/Keychains/login.keychain)
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. Try to remove any iPhone Developer item from `Keychain Access.app`. If this does not help then remove them all and add to keychain `iPhone Developer.cer` from `JailCoder.app/Contents/Resources` manually.

Answer (score 0):

I just started using JailCoder again with Xcode 5 (on OS X 10.9) and kind of rushed into it.  I ended up with the same error.

To fix, I deleted the iPhoneDeveloper.crt from Keychain Access and went through the guided patch (instead of clicking "Quick Xcode Patch" and then patching my xcodeproj), which actually has you do some important stuff to make it all work properly.

It was an oversight on my part for sure.  Just make sure you go through the Guided Patch!

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if you are part of two development teams. On the one hand Xcode requires you to install a developer profile for each of the teams. On the other hand it is confused not knowing which developer profile it shall take if you have chosen "iOS Developer" as "Code Signing Identity" in your target's "build settings".

As a workaround you could chose a concrete developer profile as "code signing identity" instead of choosing "iOS Developer". But here your team members get problems if you are selecting your personal profile.